# Huge Return Data Using Spring RMI (RmiServiceExporter and RmiProxyFactoryBean)

Tags: java, spring, rmi, wireshark

It seems that "Spring Exporter" returns the full classpath (URIs of files) besides the value of a method:

Wireshark screenshot:

[image]

In this sample application, it takes about 2KB. But in the real one, it takes more than ten 8KB tcp fragments and cause significant latency. So, I am looking for a solution to prevent passing these extra data.

The server side configuration XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...>
    <bean id="calculationBean" class="com.misc.poc.rmi.CalculationImpl"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="service" ref="calculationBean"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.misc.poc.rmi.Calculation"/>
        <property name="serviceName" value="CalculationService"/>
        <property name="servicePort" value="2000"/>
        <property name="registryPort" value="1999"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The client side configuration XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...>
    <bean id="calculationBean" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://192.168.100.94:1999/CalculationService"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.misc.poc.rmi.Calculation"/>
        <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Some related classes:

```
public interface Calculation {
    int cube(int number);
    Info greeting(String name);
}

public class Info implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public String getDesc() { return desc; }
    public void setDesc(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }
}

public class CalculationImpl implements Calculation {
    @Override
    public int cube(int number){
        return number*number*number;
    }

    @Override
    public Info greeting(String name) {
        Info res = new Info();
        res.setTitle(name);
        res.setDesc("Hello");
        return res;
    }
}
```

The RMI ReturnData:

```
E   uüg@@7ÐðiøtC}þz8^j¾¾~Q¬íw_`2hå{{R4srcom.misc.poc.rmi.Info^èù¶é¶×LdesctLjava/lang/String;Ltitleq~tÉfile:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/classes/ file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/common-1.0.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-acl-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar file:/home/user/masoud/jobs/huge-marshal/huge-marshal-app/web-server/target/server/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jarxptHellotGholi
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this list of JARs is sent as "class annotation" in the RMI response.
I've discovered that using the `SerializationDumper` tool available at https://github.com/NickstaDB/SerializationDumper.
(Tip: I had to swap the byte order in a dump from Wireshark using `dd conv=swab <data.orig >data.swapped` in order to feed it to `SerializationDumper -r`.)

```
      ....
      classAnnotations
        TC_STRING - 0x74
          newHandle 0x00 7e 00 01
          Length - 21685 - 0x54 b5
          Value - file:/app/my-rmi-server-app.jar file:/tmp/cache/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar file:/tmp/maven/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar ...
```

I'm no RMI expert, but that's not really clear to me how these paths on the RMI server could be of any use for an RMI client which obviously doesn't have access to these paths?!?

Anyway, this class annotation value is generated in https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.rmi/share/classes/sun/rmi/server/LoaderHandler.java#L194.
The algorithm makes use of so-called class/codebase loaders to determine what the value must be.
In my case, I use [Spring Boot Thin Launcher](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher) to package and run my application, so that probably has an influence on this algorithm.

The way I've found to always send an **empty** class annotation, is to override the default `RMIClassLoaderSpi` with my own:

```java
package my.app;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader;
import java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi;

public class LeanRMIClassLoaderSpi extends RMIClassLoaderSpi {
    private final RMIClassLoaderSpi delegate;

    public LeanRMIClassLoaderSpi() {
        this.delegate = RMIClassLoader.getDefaultProviderInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String codebase, String name,
                              ClassLoader defaultLoader) throws MalformedURLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        return delegate.loadClass(codebase, name, defaultLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadProxyClass(String codebase, String[] interfaces,
                                   ClassLoader defaultLoader) throws MalformedURLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        return delegate.loadProxyClass(codebase, interfaces, defaultLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader(String codebase)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return delegate.getClassLoader(codebase);
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassAnnotation(Class<?> cl) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Java system property `java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoaderSpi` must be set to `my.app.LeanRMIClassLoaderSpi` for the code in https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.rmi/share/classes/java/rmi/server/RMIClassLoader.java to pick it up.

And, voilà, your RMI traffic has been tremendously reduced — and the application still worked just fine in my case.